# New og:image size for Facebook share?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Facebook recently changed image sizes for ads, and link posts. This affects also to meta `property="og:image"`. What is new optimal size for `og:image` at Facebook? The old version was square, now it doesn't fit anymore, because new size is rectangle.

Answer (score 104):

**EDIT: The current best practices regarding Open Graph image sizes are officially outlined here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images**

---

There was a post in the Facebook developers group today, where one of the FB guys uploaded a PDF containing their new rules about image sizes – since that seems to be available only if you’re a member of the group, I uploaded it here: http://www.sendspace.com/file/ghqwhr

And they also said they will post about it in the [developer blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog) in the coming days, so keep checking there as well

To summarize the linked document:

- Minimum size in pixels is 600x315
- Recommended size is 1200x630 - Images this size will get a larger display treatment.
- Aspect ratio should be 1.91:1

Comment: Here is the latest post about it from FaceBook, see item #4:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content

Comment: The current line is "**at least**" 1200 x 630 as opposed to "recommended". But since this works out at 1:91:1, it is recommended by default I guess.

Comment: This answer is correct, I just wonder why they didn't come up with aspect ratio and recommended size that **exactly** match (630 * 1.91 = 1203.3 != 1200).

Comment: I'm curious about the recommended weight in bytes, though. More SEO question I suppose

Comment: @AlainTiemblo 8 MB is the maximum image size the scraper will accept. Apart from that, it doesn't matter much - Facebook does not serve the original image to users, but only an optimized copy put on their own CDN.

Comment: Facebook got rid of the 1200x630 recommendation: “Use images that are at least 1080 pixels in width for best display on high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that are 600 pixels in width to display image link ads. We recommend using 1:1 images in your ad creatives for better performance with image link ads.”

Comment: You can crop images in Photoshop with the crop tool ratio at 120 x 63, then save the jpg with 1200px width.

Comment: Do you still have the pdf file for sharing? The download link is dead.

Comment: @desbest no, I don't. But since this is almost ten years old now, it might be outdated anyway.

Answer (score 26):

Relying on the PDF that @CBroe posted earlier:

For best og:image results (retina ready & without being cropped) with the current Facebook Standard use:

Size: **minimum 1200 x 630px**

Ratio: **1.91:1**

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/09/18/platform-updates--facebook-ios-sdk-3-8--larger-images-for-link-page-posts--and-custom-audiences-upda/

Answer (score 13):

I'm using the minimum image size (200 x 200) and getting good results. Take a look:

[image]
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=origgami.com.br

This squared size is better than rectangles because it is the format that appears on facebook comments. The rectangle format gets cropped.

This size is on [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices)

Comment: Empirical testing shows that FB will crop your image square if it is *no larger* than 403 x 503 (https://www.qzdesign.co.uk/tests/fb/fb-image-test.php?size=403x503).  This is not documented but judging by the answers here (FB itself uses an image 325 x 325) it has been consistent behaviour for several years.

Comment: your link is not working in debuger. please recheck.

Answer (score 7):

According to facebooks [best practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images) it is like this (2016)

### Image Sizes

Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images. Images can be up to 8MB in size.
[image]

### Small Images

If your image is smaller than 600 x 315 px, it will still display in the link page post, but the size will be much smaller.
[image]

We've also redesigned link page posts so that the aspect ratio for images is the same across desktop and mobile News Feed. Try to keep your images as close to 1.91:1 aspect ratio as possible to display the full image in News Feed without any cropping.

### Minimum Image Size

The minimum image size is 200 x 200 pixels. If you try to use an image smaller than this you will see an error in the Sharing Debugger.

### Game Apps Images

There are two different image sizes to use for game apps:

Open Graph Stories Images appear in a square format. Image ratios for these apps should be 600 x 600 px.
Non-open Graph Stories Images appear in a rectangular format. You should use a 1.91:1 image ratio, such as 600 x 314 px.

Comment: I like the link directly to developers.facebook.com as fb changes it's standards periodically

Comment: My share image is 1200x630 but on some devices still displays like the second one from your post. Any idea why is that happening?

Answer (score 4):

Facebook.com og:image is 325x325 (1:1 aspect ratio, square)

https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** The image size Must be larger than (600 x 315px)

The **image size** can be any size because Faceboook re-size the image width & height.

The default height is `208px` & width is `398px` for a post permalink:

`www.facebook.com/{username}/posts/{post_id}`

But for a timeline view:

`www.facebook.com/{username}`

width is `377px` & height is `197px`

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks. Seems this follows ads sizes https://www.facebook.com/help/www/153611548180567?rdrhc

-> Desktop News Feed 400x209 px
I created 800x418px, seems working

Comment: Any size works, but as the previous answers state, if you make them at least 630x315 and keep the 1.91:1 they appear fullwidth and uncropped  wherever possible

Comment: Update 09.2014 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels

Answer (score 3):

The aspect ratio for a Facebook post image is 41:20.

To find the appropriate widths and height for your photo, you can use the [Aspect Ratio Calculator](https://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/).

Here you can select different ratios under “Common ratios:” which includes the option “1200 x 630 (Facebook)". So if the width of your photo is 1800, plug that number into the “W2” slot and it will tell you what the respective height should be.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to get the 1200x630 image working.  Facebook kept complaining that it couldn't read the image, or that it was too small (it was a jpeg image ~150Kb).

Switched to a 200x200 size image, worked perfectly.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=drift.team

Answer (score 0):

What size this image should be depends on where it is to be used.

It is up to applications, eg WhatsApp, Facebook Messenger, Reddit, etc etc to decide what to do with the image. Some use it as a square image, some as a 1:19.1 rectangle, and some use different sizes when the display environment is of different sizes even for the same application. There are no rules, and there is no way to control what applications do with the image.

So you should test out the image on your intended target application(s) and find a compromise. That applications tend to cache the image makes it a pain on the trial and error approach.