# Facebook do not use image link?

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta

I have a header that looks like this on my ASP.NET MVC webpage :

```
   <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
            <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>MyTitle</title>
            <meta content="Återanvänd på rätt vis" property="og:title">
            <meta content="website" property="og:type">
            <meta content="http://MyWebb.se/Post/Detail/392" property="og:url">
            <meta content="http://MyWebb.se/Content/Files/PostThumbnails/392.jpeg" property="og:image">
            <meta content="Some info" property="og:description">
            <meta content="MyWebb" property="og:site_name">
            <meta content="Återanvänd på rätt vis" name="twitter:title">
            <meta content="http://MyWebb.se/Post/Detail/392" name="twitter:url">
            <meta content="Some more info." name="twitter:description">
            <meta content="http://MyWebb.se/Content/Files/PostThumbnails/392.jpeg" name="twitter:image">
            <meta content="http://MyWebb.se/Content/Files/PostThumbnails/392.jpeg" name="description">
            <meta content="keywords" name="keywords">
            <link href="/favicon.ico?v=2" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
            <link href="/Content/Theme/MainTheme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">        
    </head>
```

And when checking it with this tool : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug it does fetch the image.

But when I paste the url in to the wallpost it will only fetch title and desciption, no image. If the thumb however is square the image load just fine.

Why is "not  square" images working? Should I generate empty space on all my thumbs(transparent borders with png) so they get a square format? Or is there another solution?

Maybe its because I'm missing the end tag for the meta data? But then the test tool should not fine the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the og:image was of to small format, after this was fixed it worked just fine without stating the size.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the image type, width and height as per the example on the Facebook Developer docs - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/open-graph-object/

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/lamb-full.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="3523">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="2372">
```

See also this SO answer - [New og:image size for Facebook share?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835027/new-ogimage-size-for-facebook-share) - it sounds like there are minimum dimensions for the images.