# Facebook Open Graph image meta tag not working with base64 image

Tags: javascript, php, html, base64, facebook-opengraph

I have a webpage that ask you to type 5 thing. Those things will be placed in a `<table>`. After that, the user confirms the 5 options and, using canvas, I make an image of this table.
I want to present this image on a facebook post when user click on "share".

My code, via php post, is already changing the

```
<meta property="og:image"         content=""/>
```

and the content now has the base64 url returned by

```
canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

but the image is not being recognized by the facebook page.

what can I do?

Comment: Have you inspected it with devtools? sometimes it will throw an error if the image is too large

Comment: My image is always 620x240. I think that is ok, right?

Comment: It's too small actually, "Minimum size in pixels is 600x315" http://stackoverflow.com/a/18846258/6252597

Comment: @Cameron637 I made it now 620x340, still not workin. All the other tags are working fine, just this image. I think that base64 won't work

Comment: How long ago did you add the image? Facebook caches their open graph data so if you changed it recently it's probably still using old data

Comment: That is a problem... my image is dynamic. Since every user will put 5 different text into the <table>, in the end the image will be differente, generated in the moment that the user pressed the post button.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how often Facebook rescrapes the data but it's likely about once a day so that probably won't work.  You might have to figure something else out

Comment: Same problem here..